# Youtube Embed: Controlos (Play/Pause and Fullscreen) does not show up in Firefox

Tags: iframe, youtube, embed

I use the following embed code to embed a youtube video on my wordpress page:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%"
  src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/LjQtRr4CKcc?
  modestbranding=1&
  showinfo=0&
  rel=0&
  autohide=1&
  controls=1"
  frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

In Chrome the controls for play/pause and fullscreen show up. However, in Firefox they don't. Still, if I know where to click, I can play/pause the video and also set it to fullscreen. So the functionality is there, but not the symbols...

Can anyone tell me what I need to change, in order to show the buttons in Firefox for embedded youtube videos?

UPDATE: interestingly, when I load the page in "private mode" of firefox, the buttons show up.
UPDATE2: clearing the cache in firefox did the trick. So, obviously the issue was not the code, but my local firefox. Still, a friend of mine has the same issue, leading me to think that this is a strange issue..

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in FF44 (I read on mozilla forum). Will be fixed in v45 next month.
You should embed the YouTube video with https:// not with http:// then FF will show the controls.